# Using PyCapsule in Cython

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython

### Summary

I need to store a C struct inside a Python object for use in other parts boosted with Cython. I believe a PyCapsule is best suited for this purpose, but the results of my code is not what I am expecting. While the pointer address is correctly returned, the memory appears to have been freed.

### Details

I am new to Cython and I am learning to use it to speed up part of my code. For the purpose of asking the question, I have simplified my code and an int is used instead of a struct.

I wrote CythonTest.pyx according to my understanding of the [PyCapsule documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/capsule.html) and compiled it with setup.py using the standard command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

CythonTest.pyx

```
#cython: language_level=3

from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_New, PyCapsule_IsValid, PyCapsule_GetPointer

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        cdef int test = 10
        cdef const char *name = "test"
        self.vars = PyCapsule_New(<void *>&test, name, NULL)
        
        # Print pointer address
        print("{0:x}".format(<unsigned long long>test))
        
    def peek(self):
        cdef const char *name = "test"
        if not PyCapsule_IsValid(self.vars, name):
            raise ValueError("invalid pointer to parameters")
        cdef int *test = <int *>PyCapsule_GetPointer(self.vars, name)
        print(test[0])
        
        # Print pointer address
        print("{0:x}".format(<unsigned long long>test))
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("CythonTest.pyx"))
```

Then, I run this with the following Python script.

```
from CythonTest import Test

test = Test()
print(test.vars)
test.peek()
```

The console prints out the following:

```
cbde7ebe70
<capsule object "test" at 0x0000027516467930>
0
cbde7ebe70
```

It appears that the pointer has been successfully stored in a PyCapsule and retrieved as indicated by the identical address. However, 0 is now stored inside the address instead of 10. I am aware that using an int may have caused it to be garbage collected and changed the nature of the problem, but the same issue is observed when using PyMem_Malloc as well.

So the question is: what is the correct way of using PyCapsule?

### Environment

- Compiler: Visual Studio Express 2015
- Cython: 0.26
- OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)
- Python: 3.5.3
- Spyder (IDE): 3.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a local variable (in C) so does not exist beyond the end of the `__init__` function, and therefore when you try to access it again in `peek` the memory has already been used for something else.

You can allocate memory for `test` of the heap instead, so that the variable persists as long as you need (you need to create a destructor to deallocate it though).

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

# destructor
cdef void free_ptr(object cap):
   # This should probably have some error checking in
   # or at very least clear any errors raised once it's done
   free(PyCapsule_GetPointer(cap,PyCapsule_GetName(cap)))

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
       cdef int* test = malloc(sizeof(int)) 
       test[0] = 10
       cdef const char *name = "test"
       self.vars = PyCapsule_New(<void *>test, name, &free_ptr)

       # etc
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not currently able to test this. I'm pretty sure I've identified the problem correctly, but can't guarantee the replacement code works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, allocating memory for the struct as well (rather than just its members) has solved the problem. Could you explain what sort of error checking is required? Will the PyCapsule_IsValid I have used be sufficient? As a side note, should I post my fully working solution? If so, should it be appended to the question or as an answer?

Comment: `PyCapsule_IsValid` is definitely a good idea. You probably also want to test that none of the `PyCapsule_*` functions you call raise an error. There's no way of returning the error from the destructor (since it returns void), so you probably just want to print and clear it: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#printing-and-clearing

Comment: If you think your full working solution would be useful to others then feel free to post it. If you do decide post it should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following the pointers from DavidW's answer (pun *intended*), I went ahead to amend my code to make it fully functional with C structs and a bit of error handling. I used the PyMem versions of malloc and free here since they are said to work more nicely.

```
#cython: language_level=3

from cpython.exc cimport PyErr_Occurred, PyErr_Print
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free
from cpython.pycapsule cimport *

cdef struct params:
    double *param1

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        cdef int index
        cdef params *test = <params *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(params))
        test.param1 = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(double))
        test.param1[0] = 0.5
        cdef const char *name = "test"
        self.vars = PyCapsule_New(<void *>test, name, NULL)
        print(test.param1[0])

    def peek(self):
        cdef const char *name = "test"
        if not PyCapsule_IsValid(self.vars, name):
            raise ValueError("invalid pointer to parameters")
        cdef params *test = <params *>PyCapsule_GetPointer(self.vars, name)
        print(test.param1[0])

    def __del__(self):
        cdef const char *name = "test"
        cdef params *pointer = <params *>PyCapsule_GetPointer(self.vars, name)
        if PyErr_Occurred():
            PyErr_Print()
        else:
            PyMem_Free(test.param1)
            PyMem_Free(test)
```

As usual, basic checks should have been done in memory allocation in the form of:

```
if not pointer:
    raise MemoryError()
```

But these are omitted for the sake of clarity. The same goes for cleaning up after an unsuccessful partial initialisation.